# Is there a way to disable the Title and Subtitle in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, react-native, highcharts

I'm just going to hardcode it in using html that is around the graph, I don't want to use the built in.

I don't see a "disable: true"       option in the API.

Can anybody help me out here.

How do you disable the title / subtitle in highcharts?

(if you simply leave the text blank it still carves out a whitespace in that spot where the title is, i'd like to not have this happen)

Answer (score 185):

Setting the title text to an empty string is the way to do it.

No space is created for the title in that case:

without text: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/JVNjs/284/

with text: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/JVNjs/286/

```
title:{
    text:''
}
```

If you want less space than is left in that case, simply set your 'marginTop' to 0

{{**edit due to numerous comments**:

As pointed out a number of times below, the documentation now states `text: null` as the method to achieve this. (2023 Update: `null` now throws a type error, and `undefined` is recommended.)

Either method achieves the desired result.

Comment: Could you take a look at this for me? I've done all the suggestions here and there is still a huge white space, (see the print button floating in space in the top right?)  http://goo.gl/jHR5l

Comment: I think I may have solved it. I had my legend aligned to the top, and the floating on the legend was set to false, it created a space for it there. I set the floating on the legend to true, and now it has pushed the rest of the chart further up.

Comment: As pointed out below, setting the text to null is the documented solution.

Comment: As of version `5.0.9` this is incorrect. Setting text so an empty string generated default title text such as 'Chart Title' and 'Values'.

Comment: @mwilson I am looking at the demo from the link in the answer above, which is (at the time of this comment) using 5.0.9, and it still works with either `null` or `''`. Can you elaborate or demonstrate?

Comment: @jbriggs I went back to the highcharts web site and put one of their demos into a JSFiddle. I stand corrected and simply passing an empty string works. What I do find strange, is that in my example (on my web app), passing an empty string ends up with auto-generated title such as 'Chart Title.' Can't seem to reproduce it with their stuff which probably means I'm doing something different/introducing an edge case. I saw a couple of other threads that talked about the same behavior I was experiencing, but I guess that's not the case.

Comment: You can also set the text to undefined as suggested in the highcharts docs.  /**
     * (Highcharts, Highstock, Highmaps, Gantt) The title of the chart. To
     * disable the title, set the `text` to `undefined`.
     */
    text?: string;

Answer (score 75):

From the [highcharts doc](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#title):

> text: String 
>   The title of the chart. To disable the title, set the text to null. Defaults to Chart title.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/daub10dr/

```
title:{
      text: null
      }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, don't know why this is not the accepted answer. All other solutions provided below are just workarounds.

Comment: May be the user that asked the question just forget to flag it as "accepted"

Comment: probably because the question was appropriately answered 6 months before this answer was posted...

Comment: "appropriately"?? what answer do you mean?? ;-)

Comment: This is correct with the "new" api. When the question was asked this was not supported. So both are valid depending on the version.

Answer (score 45):

I prefer this method :

```
title: {
    text: '',
    style: {
        display: 'none'
    }
},
subtitle: {
    text: '',
    style: {
        display: 'none'
    }
},
```

Comment: For newer version refer to answer from Plastic with ´text: null´

Comment: This is a solution when you need the title to be there for export the data, but not render it.

Answer (score 20):

Very simple! In the latest version of Highcharts just set title and subtitle properties to false.

```
{
title: false,
subtitle: false
}
```

Find the working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/samuellawrentz/hkqnvm7k/4/

Answer (score 13):

You can always do this:

```
chart:{
    marginTop: 30
}

title:{
    text: ''
}
```

That worked for me :-)

***note:***
 this answer was for `version 2.*`, for newer versions there are better answers.

Answer (score 13):

It´s simple...
Only set the title´s text to null. Like this

```
    $(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    title: {
        text: null  
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});
```

});

see@APIreference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#title.text

Comment: Base on the document, it becomes `undefined` since this commit https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/commit/c2359b24d5d2396a21759ecdd6548deb7a4cc8d5

Answer (score 10):

Set the text field to *null*

From the documentation at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#title.text

> text: String
>
> The title of the chart. To disable the title, set the text to null. Defaults to Chart title.

Comment: Base on the document, it becomes undefined since this commit https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/commit/c2359b24d5d2396a21759ecdd6548deb7a4cc8d5

Answer (score 8):

According the Highcharts doc, the correct way is to set 'text' to null.

i.e

```
title : {
    text : null
}
```

Comment: > The title of the chart. To disable the title, set the text to undefined.

Answer (score 5):

In react-native below code worked for me,

```
  title: {
    style : {
      display : 'none'
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

For those that use Typescript you can set the Highcharts.TitleOptions to hide the chart title.

```
title: {
  text: undefined
},
subtitle: {
  text: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution

```
title: {
    text: null
},
subtitle: {
    text: null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just write a JSON object

```
title : {
  style : {
    display : 'none'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me!!!

`title:false`

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of a hack but you can also try that:

```
title: {
    text: '<span class="hidden">My custom Hello</span>',
    align:"left",
    useHTML:true
}
```