# Circular Graph Html

Tags: php, html, css, graph

I am looking to make a Circular Graph like this

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6aez.png)

What I am after doing is getting total dmg dealt by a team and dmg from a certain person on that team and then using that to calculate the dmg that person dealt out of all the teams damage.

Then it should make a graph like shown above. I have looked around and can not find anything that does this.

And is usable with php.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using a Javascript library, you may want to look into Highcharts. This is what I used to accomplish the same request as yours.

```
            data: [["Firefox",6],["MSIE",4],["Chrome",7]],
            size: '60%',
            innerSize: '70%',
```

Here's a jsFiddle example that you can check out: http://jsfiddle.net/HpdwR/1989/ . Here's a link to someone on another stackoverlfow with the same question on how to do it with highcharts: [Highcharts donut chart without inner pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678684/highcharts-donut-chart-without-inner-pie)

Comment: How would I make it so it only the actual, Graph and none of the white background, title, menu and url at bottom right ?

Comment: The nice thing about Highcharts is you have a lot of customization options. This API documentation will show to how to style the graph: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style .

Comment: No background: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7744755/5437264
No title: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19008457/5437264
No logo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15460172/5437264

Comment: Try this js chart library. https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/index.html